# Dell Inspiron 1545 - Battery will not charge

Tags: laptop, battery, dell-inspiron

I recently bought a new battery that is compatible with the laptop. It ran off the battery just fine initially and then after draining the battery for the second time in order to break-in the battery, the power icon in the bottom right of my screen said that the battery is plugged in but not charging. This problem also occurred before I purchased the new battery with the battery that came with the laptop.

I have tried looking around for a solid solution for a while now and have had no luck. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your power adapter could be the issue. Try another power adapter if you are able, most Dell laptops use the same cable.

If changing the power adpter doesn't fix your problem, you can try the following steps:

- Turn off the laptop before removing battery and charger.
- Press and hold the power button for 5-10 seconds.
- Put battery back in and try again.

Here are a couple links with similar information:

[Battery Not Charging Inspiron 1525](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-133690-battery-not-charging-inspiron-1525)

[Wikihow Guide for Troubleshooting a battery that doesn't charge](http://www.wikihow.com/Troubleshoot-a-Dell-Inspiron-1545-Battery-That-Doesn't-Charge)